# Why can't Finder pass a single folder to an Automator Action?

Tags: finder, automator

I'm trying to create an Automator service which "receives selected files or folders".  If I select a single file in Finder, then go to the Finder:Services menu, my service shows up.  If I select two folders in Finder, I also see my service. But if I select only a single folder, the same menu says "No services apply".

Why doesn't the finder services menu recognize that my service is available to be run when only a single folder is selected?  How can I run my service?

Comment: You can. I have written Services which open a single Folder in my Application. Without detail of what you have tried it is difficult to comment.

Comment: @Milliways There aren't really many details to share because I've just come up with a default service, set where to receive files from, and created a "Run Shell Script" action to catch the files.